# Umbraco CMS stripping ALT tags from images when content saved

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, strip, alt-attribute

Umbraco is taking:

```
<img alt="Your Title - for example Mr., Mrs., Ms."
 src="../media/21283/q16x16.gif" width="16" height="15"/>
```

And turning it into

```
<img alt="" src="/media/21283/q16x16.gif" width="16" height="15" rel="16,15"/>
```

If I alter the alt tag after this processing then the alt tag is saved.

Comment: Whch version of Umbraco are you using, and what are you using to enter your content (I'm assuming the WYSIWYG rich text editor).

Comment: Using version 3.03 its apparently  modified/bugfixed.  I am adding html vis the html button in the editor, which embeds this within the WYSIWYG editor

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this has something to do with the 'validElements' setting in TinyMCE (the wysiwyg editor)

in version 4 this is edited in the /config/tinyMCEConig.config file. Look for validElements. It could be the same in 3.03?

Each allowed HTML tag along with it's allowed attributes is listed in this section in the config file.
Ensure you have a something like this in there:

**img**[id|dir........border|**alt=**|title.......]